# Visual Studio C/C++ Project with MASM code produces error `error A2008: syntax error : .`

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

I have a Visual Studio C/C++ project with a single assembly file `main.asm` in it. During the process of building the project I get the errors:

> ```
> 1>main.asm(5): error A2008: syntax error : .
> 1>main.asm(6): error A2008: syntax error : .
> 1>main.asm(7): error A2008: syntax error : .
> 1>main.asm(8): error A2008: syntax error : ,
> 1>main.asm(20): error A2008: syntax error : INVOKE
> ```

My code for **main.asm** is:

```
; program 3.1
; sample Assembly program - MASM (32-bit)


.386                                ; Line 5
.MODEL FLAT, stdcall                ; Line 6
.STACK 4096                         ; Line 7
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD ; Line 8

.data
sum DWORD 0

.code
_main PROC
mov eax, 25
mov ebx, 50
add ebx, ebx
mov sum, eax

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0               ; Line 20
_main ENDP
END
```

A screenshot of Visual Studio with my code and the errors:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCtKg.jpg]

Why am I getting these errors and how can I fix them?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCtKg.jpg

Comment: There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64302264/edit) button below your question, to edit the question. You should not put this info in a comment.  (I added the picture to your question)

Comment: A similar question was asked before (and answered), see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611550/error-a2008-syntax-error

Comment: BTW posting code as TEXT, not as picture is much nicer for the question....

Comment: This is so frustrating I do not understand what it is its saying in that link Luuk.  Why cant I just start programming.  Ive already setup my assembly environment.  I am so confused as to why its not working.  Ive been working on this for hours.  Why am I getting a syntax error at line 5 in that image Ive already tried getting rid of the comments but thats not the issue.

Comment: It looks like the "description" column is narrow and cutting off part of the description.  Looking at the full message might help, or at least copy/paste it into your question [as text](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).  Are you sure Visual Studio is treating that source file as asm, not C++?

Comment: yes I was able to fix my problem @MichaelPetch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the errors you are showing on the line starting with `.MODEL`, `.STACK`, and `.386` I can only gather that you are building for a 64-bit target rather than a 32-bit target. You likely also received errors related to the `INVOKE` directive as well. None of these directives are supported by 64-bit MASM and thus are generating errors. In 64-bit code the model is always assumed to be flat and the calling conventions for CDECL, STDCALL, THISCALL, FASTCALL etc are all the same and follow the [Windows 64-bit Calling Convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019).

You have two choices:

- Build a 32-bit application. In Visual Studio as part of the menu bars there is a pull down box for the platform. The platform can be adjusted in the toolbar by changing `x64` to `x86`:

  [image]
- Modify the code to work with 64-bit code. To build in 64-bit you have to replace `INVOKE` with `CALL` and the [Windows 64-bit calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019) must be used. You can remove the `.STACK`, `.MODEL`, and `.386` directives. Modify the definition of the external procedures by declaring them `EXTERN` with a `PROC` type. The code could look something like:

  ```
  ; program 3.1
  ; sample Assembly program - MASM (64-bit)

  extern ExitProcess:PROC
  public mainCRTStartup

  .data
  sum DWORD 0

  .code
  mainCRTStartup PROC       ; Use mainCRTStartup if making a CONSOLE app without
                            ;   any C/C++ files AND if you haven't overridden the
                            ;   ENTRY point in the Visual Studio Project.
    sub rsp, 8+32           ; Align stack on 16 byte boundary and allocate 32 bytes
                            ;   of shadow space for call to ExitProcess. Shadow space
                            ;   is required for 64-bit Windows Calling Convention as
                            ;   is ensuring the stack is aligned on a 16 byte boundary
                            ;   at the point of making a call to a C library function
                            ;   or doing a WinAPI call.
    mov eax, 25
    mov ebx, 50
    add ebx, ebx
    mov sum, eax

    xor ecx, ecx            ; Set Error Code to 0 (RCX is 1st parameter)
    call ExitProcess
  mainCRTStartup ENDP
  END
  ```

  The entry point may be different for your environment depending on whether you are creating a GUI or CONSOLE application and whether your project has a C/C++ file present.

  Function names in the 64-bit calling convention are not required to start with an underscore unlike 32-bit Windows code.